# Programmatically loading all colors from res/color

Tags: android, colors

The question says it all.

Is there an opportunity to programmatically load all Colors from `res/color` into an Array?

If you got at least the `ApplicationContext` it's possible to load one color for example like this:

```
context.getResources().getColor(R.color.MyColor);
```

But i want to load all into an Array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will iterate over all color references and load the actual colors to a sparse array

```
SparseIntArray colors = new SparseIntArray();
Field[] refs = R.color.class.getFields(); //your R
for (Field f : refs) {
  try {
    int ref = f.getInt(null);
    int color = getApplicationContext().getResources().getColor(ref);
    colors.put(ref, color);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Suppose you have a color named `my_color`, you'd get it like this:

```
int color = colors.get(R.color.my_color);
```

Credit for an idea goes to @snachmsm.

**Note:** Run a test to see how much computing time you actually save using this method, you should not use reflection if you can avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Field[] colors = R.color.class.getFields(); //your R
for (Field f : colors) {
    try {
        Log.i("colors", "R.color." + f.getName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

check `Field` class and its methods in [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/reflect/Field.html)

edit:
`Field` might have working method `getInt`, you can try, I can't right now :) even if not you are getting string of resource like this`"R.color.red"` inside `Log.i`, then you can convert it to Color using this method:

```
private Color getColorResourceByName(String fgetname) {
  int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(fgetname, "color", getPackageName());
  return getString(resId);
}
```

add each `Color` to an `ArrayList` or whatever set you want while iterating throug `Field`

Comment: This will load the array with color reference numbers not the actual colors.